# How can I handle an empty namespace with XDocument.XPathEvaluate?

Tags: .net, xpath, linq-to-xml, xml-namespaces

I'm trying to use XDocument and XPathEvaluate to get values from the woot.com feed. I'm handling other namespaces fine, but this example is giving me problems.

```
     <rss xmlns:a10="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" version="2.0">
      <channel>    
        <category text="Comedy" xmlns="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd">
</category> 
<!-- this is a problem node, notice 'xmlns=' --!>
```

So I try this:

```
  XmlNamespaceManager man = new XmlNamespaceManager(nt);
    man.AddNamespace("ns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/");
// i've also tried man.AddNamespace("ns", string.Empty);
    xDocument.Namespace = man;
    var val = xDocument.XPathEvaluate("/rss/channel/ns:category/@text", xDocument.Namespace);
```

val is always null. I'm using ns: from the suggestion from VS 2010 XPath Navigator plugin. Any thoughts on how to handle this?

Comment: What is `xdwn.Namespace` ? xdwn is not defined in the provided code.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev - it should have been xDocument, I've edited the question. Thanks for checking my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The element `category` is in namespace `http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd`. It's not an empty namespace. It just isn't given a prefix in input XML.

```
man.AddNamespace("ns", "http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd");
...
xDocument.XPathEvaluate("/rss/channel/ns:category/@text", xDocument.Namespace);
```

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> man.AddNamespace("ns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/");
> ```

Here is the error: you bind to the wrong namespace.

**Must be:**

```
man.AddNamespace("ns", "http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd");
```